# Update table to set the rows of a second group to be the same as the first row of the first group in sql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

How do i update my table in sql so that the rows of the second group are the same as the first row of that group.
Please find the attached screen shot for better understanding.

Current and Expected Results:

[image]

Comment: can anyone please advise on this ?

Comment: can anyone please suggest on this ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to provide sample data as DDL+DML (create table and insert into statements) as well as your current attempt.

Comment: Define "first" for your second group. Right now within group 1 you have `(24418,Donald)` followed by `(24419,Kalamaz)`, but unless you specify the order as part of your query, the SQL language does not guarantee you'll see the same order next time you view the data. I expect it's probably by group2id, but I need to hear it from you or I'm only guessing.

Comment: Also... a big part of the reason you haven't had a response yet is you used an image to communicate your sample data. Lots of people who might have helped you won't ever see that image. You need to use code block or `<pre>` block in the question editor to share your sample data as text.

Answer (score 0):

Create Table Script

```
CREATE TABLE CurrentTable
(
Group1ID INT,
Group1Name VARCHAR(100),
Group2ID INT,
Group2Name  VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO CurrentTable VALUES ('360943','Group 1','24418','Donald')
INSERT INTO CurrentTable VALUES ('360943','Group 1','24419','Kalamaz')
INSERT INTO CurrentTable VALUES ('360944','Group 2','24410','Adam')
INSERT INTO CurrentTable VALUES ('360944','Group 2','24411','Suzan')
```

Now Table Looks like

```
Group1ID    Group1Name  Group2ID    Group2Name
360943      Group 1     24418       Donald
360943      Group 1     24419       Kalamaz
360944      Group 2     24410       Adam
360944      Group 2     24411       Suzan
```

Update Script

```
UPDATE O SET O.Group2ID = (SELECT TOP 1 Group2ID FROM CurrentTable I WHERE O.Group1ID = I.Group1ID),
O.Group2Name = (SELECT TOP 1 Group2Name FROM CurrentTable I WHERE O.Group1ID = I.Group1ID)
FROM CurrentTable O
```

Post Running Update

```
Group1ID    Group1Name  Group2ID    Group2Name
360943      Group 1     24418       Donald
360943      Group 1     24418       Donald
360944      Group 2     24410       Adam
360944      Group 2     24410       Adam
```